# iPhone SDK: Errors when replacing string occurrences

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdata, exc-bad-access

I am trying to replace occurances of a string in a few different steps, I am using:

```
NSString *doc = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
doc = [doc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"###DATA###" withString:cord];
doc = [doc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"###NAME###" withString:ride.title];
doc = [doc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"###DESC###" withString:ride.description];

[doc release];
```

I am first getting text from a file and wanting to replace a few string with me own.  But, I am getting the following error when running this:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
[Switching to thread 13059]
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)
```

I am not understanding why I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.  What am I trying to release that has already been released?!

Comment: have you checked the return value of doc?

Comment: have you tried providing a sample string such as @"hello ###DATA### bye" and doing the same substitution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *doc = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
doc = [doc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"###DATA###" withString:cord];
```

When you assign to `doc` in the second line, you lose your reference to the string you originally created.

```
[doc release];
```

In the last line, when you release the string, you're not releasing the original. You're releasing whatever it is now, which is the result of the line before that. So the original string leaks, you overrelease the replacement, and that overrelease causes a crash. Either autorelease your original string when you create it (and drop the final `release` call) or use a different temporary for the modified strings you make in the middle.

For example, change the code to:

```
NSString *doc = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
doc = [doc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"###DATA###" withString:cord];
doc = [doc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"###NAME###" withString:ride.title];
doc = [doc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"###DESC###" withString:ride.description];
```

And it won't leak. If it still crashes after that, the crash will be from a different cause (such as you using the string later on without having held onto it somewhere.) GDB is your friend--check what it says in its backtrace.

Comment: Ok, but how can I then use doc later?  I am wanting to assign that string to to an email later: self.emailData = [doc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  which now crashes.

Comment: You need to read up on your Objective-C memory management. You don't understand how it works. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: I normally DO understand it.  But this situation is confusing me.

Comment: Well, this question suggests you don't understand it as well as you think. That's not a point of shame--it can take time to get used to it. That you don't know how to resolve the crash on your own, though, suggests you need to read up more. Once you have, try running with GDB attached. (Run -> Debug - Breakpoints On, or Cmd+Option+Y.) It will break when the crash happens and show you the backtrace. That ought to help you figure out exactly what's causing problems.